# Drools Queries and Java OutOfMemory

Tags: drools, rules

In other question ([Drools Java OutOfMemory Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19788566/2835490)) I had a rule that generated an exception Java OutOfMemory. An user told me that I need to use queries.

Well, now I have a query that checks if there are 5 facts that have the same value (5 facts with the same value in the last 7 days). When I work with a lot of facts I have the same problem.

I'm testing with this query:

```
query multipleRequests(Fact r_A, Integer exits)
    $exits := Number(intValue>=5) from accumulate(
         r_B:Fact(viewed==true,INT_IP == r_A.INT_IP,Tools.check(SOL_FEC, r_A.SOL_FEC) <=7),
         count(r_B)
         )
end
```

And this rule:

```
rule "MUL_04_WithQuery"
no-loop true
when
    r_A:Fact(viewed==false)
    $numbers : multipleRequests(r_A;)    
then
        modify (r_A) {
            setViewed(true),
            setEST_EST_FRA(1),
            setEST_PRO_EST(1)
        }
end
```

But I can not get the expected performance. Also, when I try with more than 100 facts, I get, too, a Java heap problem.

I don't understand. Is it the correct query for my problem???

Comment: What is your expected performance, number of facts and heap size? I tried your rule with 1000 Facts and can complete within 0.5 sec. (drools version: 5.5.0-final)

Comment: Less than 1 sec for 1000 facts is a good value. But I don't get the query or correct rule

Comment: Finally I decided to use a Data Base to develop these queries :(